# storing object in user defaults swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm new to swift and trying to figure out the best way to store user defaults. Here are my 3 initial VC classes of my app where i pass data from the on boarding view, to the start your plan view, to the user info (profile view) - which is where i need to store defaults for users. My issue is - the only user default that is storing is "name" and "monthly" pay seems to work as well. But the "daily budget default" and "daily savings default" (which are doubles) don't seem to store and appear on the 3rd screen, (users profile). I am not getting the correct reference.

**1st snippet** of code is from the on boarding view controller where i collect their info - to keep things short I'm only showing the calculateData IBAction. As of now - this is where i am trying to grab their user defaults.

**2nd VC** of info is the view directly after on boarding, where the user can review their info - once they press start from this VC- i create an new user object (should i just create an array of new User objects and store it under NSUserDefaults here?)

**3rd VC** - this is the actual user profile, where i need all of the user defaults to show. I am going to set this as the initial view controller & set up in app delegate, to load this page first if a user has previously done the on boarding screen.

Please and thank you for any help!

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

   @IBAction func calculateDataButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    customerName = nameTextField.text!


    if let payTotal = Double(monthlyAmountTextField.text!){
        monthlyEarning = payTotal
    }

    if let savingsNumber = Double(desiredSavingsTextField.text!){
        desiredSavingsAmount = savingsNumber

    }

    else {
        displayLabel.text = "Enter input as so: 1299.39"

    }


    budgetForEachDay = ((monthlyEarning - desiredSavingsAmount) / 4.0) / 7.0
    savingsForEachDay = (desiredSavingsAmount / 4.0) / 7.0


    UserDefaults.standard.set(nameTextField.text, forKey: "name")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(monthlyAmountTextField.text, forKey: "monthlyPay")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(savingsForEachDay, forKey: "dailySavingsDefault")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(budgetForEachDay, forKey: "dailyBudgetDefault")
    //THE 4 USER DEFAULTS I NEED TO SAVE
```

Here is the NEXT CLASS THAT THE SEGUE LOADS Too- i create a new User object here - should i perhaps store User Defaults in a newUserObject array instead of how i am trying to go about it ?

```
import UIKit

class StartYourPlanViewController: UIViewController {

    var nameFieldPassedOver : String?
    var monthlyEarningPassedOver : Double?
    var desiredSavingsPassedOver : Double?
    var budgetToSpend : Double = 55.3
    var saveEachDay : Double = 55.5



    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var monthtlyEarningLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var desiredSavingsLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nameLabel.text = nameFieldPassedOver

        monthtlyEarningLabel.text = "\(monthlyEarningPassedOver!)" 
        monthtlyEarningLabel.isHidden = true

        desiredSavingsLabel.text = "\(desiredSavingsPassedOver!)"
        desiredSavingsLabel.isHidden = true


    }


    func makeNewUserObject(){

        let newUser = UserInfo(name: nameFieldPassedOver!, iWantToSave : desiredSavingsPassedOver!, monthlyIncome: monthlyEarningPassedOver!, budgetEachDay : budgetToSpend, youSaveEachDay : saveEachDay)


        newUser.printUserBio()

    }


    @IBAction func startPlanButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {


        makeNewUserObject()



        performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToYourUserInfoView", sender: self)

    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


       if segue.identifier == "GoToYourUserInfoView"{

           let userInfoVC = segue.destination as! UserInfoViewController


            userInfoVC.userNamePassedOver = nameFieldPassedOver
            userInfoVC.userDailyBudgetPassedOver = budgetToSpend
            userInfoVC.userMonthlyEarningsPassedOver = monthlyEarningPassedOver
            userInfoVC.userDesiredSavingsPassedOver = desiredSavingsPassedOver
            userInfoVC.userDailySavingsPassedOver = saveEachDay

        }

    }


}
```

AND here will end up being my main and initial VC- where i display the users information for them. I need to Set the default values of user defaults so that they appear on this page everytime an existing user opens the app

```
class UserInfoViewController : ViewController {

    var userNamePassedOver : String?
    var userDailyBudgetPassedOver : Double?
    var userDailySavingsPassedOver : Double?
    var userMonthlyEarningsPassedOver : Double?
    var userDesiredSavingsPassedOver : Double?
    var newAmountPassedBack : Double = 0.0

    let monthlyPay = "monthlyPay"
    let name = "name"
    let dailySavingsDefault = "dailySavingsDefault"
    let dailyBudgetDefault = "dailyBudgetDefault"


    @IBOutlet weak var dailySavingsNumberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dailySpendingLimitLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        if let name = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKeyPath: name) as? String{
            userNameLabel.text = name
        }

        if let monthlyPay = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKeyPath: monthlyPay) as? String{

            userMonthlyEarningsPassedOver = Double(monthlyPay)

        }

      if let dailySavingsDefault = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKeyPath: dailySavingsDefault) as? String{



            dailySavingsNumberLabel.text = dailySavingsDefault



        }

       if let dailyBudgetDefault = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKeyPath: dailyBudgetDefault) as? String {

            dailySpendingLimitLabel.text = dailyBudgetDefault


        }


    }
```

Comment: what is your actual requirement?? And make your question neat so that everyone can read and understand.

Comment: Im sorry for that, its like 3 am and ive been looking at this code for 6 hours. This is What i need to do exactly. On the signup page i have 3 inputs from the user- their name, monthly income and desired savings amount. With those 3 inputs, i can calculate a daily budget, and a daily savings amount (which you see are on my 1st VC directly above user defaults). I need to store all of those in User Defaults - because i need to present that data to the user every time they open the app.

Comment: I am confused on whether i should store the User Defaults in an array of of objects (because this object will already hold all of this data - see 2nd Class "newUser" object).. Or, do i create the user defaults when the user inputs the data on the onboard screen (first View Controller)

Comment: Can you  let me know screen sequences.

Comment: yes of course - the FIRST screen is the on boarding screen, it has 3 simple text inputs - name, monthly pay and desired savings. I also calculate a daily budget and daily savings goal on this screen. SECOND screen is where they confirm and click "start my savings plan"- in the IBAction to start their plan, i create a new user object, which takes a name, how much they want to save, monthly income, daily budget to spend and daily savings. THIRD screen is their profile - this is where i need to display their user defaults, because this will be the initial VC.

Comment: I never seen anyone to get user input in boarding screen. Whatsoever, do it boarding screen because, only here you get the data from user. In rest of screen get data from user default and use it. Is there any other issue??

Comment: Well my issue is that the user defaults are not showing on the 3rd VC. i can't get them to show on the display labels on the 3rd screen.

Answer (score 5):

Initially,  You have to archive the objects into NSData then we can save it to the UserDefault and retrieve it from UserDefault when needed.

Example is shown below:-

1) Save object to UserDefault

```
let groups = [Group(id: 1, name: "group1", shortname: "g1"), Group(id: 2, name: "group2", shortname: "g2")]

var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: groups)
userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "groups")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

2) Retrieve Object from UserDefault

```
let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "groups") as! Data
let decodedGroups = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Group]
```

Comment: Hell Chetan, thank you for response. So After I archive object into NSdata and save it to user default. How am I able to set labels on their user profile to reflect their saved user defaults? For instance- the object I’m saving has properties of name, how much they want to save, a daily budget, & a daily savings number. I’m confused on how to get the saved data and display it within the labels. Please and thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you set the data is `userdefault` after it you have to synchronise your `userdefault`  so that `userdefault` saves the pending data. Make sure you won't have any typo mistake with `userdefault` identifier.

Comment: Pretty sure thats not true anymore https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/nsuserdefaults-is-planned-to-deprecated-cc185e19e6f8

Comment: @Flexicoder There it written that **Its planned to be deprecated**, it doesn't mean it is depricated. And second thing it is not official Apple Doc. So pls first check from [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize)

Comment: which actually states **this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.**

Comment: @Flexicoder If there is any pending data to be updated in the `userdefault` then use this else there is no need to use this func.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store structs on UserDefaults:

```
// Save the selected timeZone on UserDefaults
    if let encodedCity = try? JSONEncoder().encode(cityAndTimeZone) {
       UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedCity, forKey: "cityAndTimeZone")
    }


// To restore struct from UserDefaults
if let decodedData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "cityAndTimeZone") as? Data {
        if let cityAndTimeZone = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CityAndTimeZone.self, from: decodedData) {
            timezoneLabel.text = cityAndTimeZone.city
        }
    }
```